# moq/Nunit - No tests are loaded or are disabled

Tags: nunit, moq

When I try to run the tests, I get a message saying that the tests are not loaded or are disabled. I cannot see how to enable or activate the test code that has been created.

This seems to be a common error when installing/using addon Nunit or Moq but I have yet to find a link that has a solution.

If you know how to solve this problem please let us all know :) Thanks.

Visual Studio 2008 SP1 3.5SP1 .net
The Microsoft tests run ok.

Comment: What runner are you using ? TestDriven ? Resharper ?

Comment: Resharper? NO. I was expecting it to work by menu/Test/Run all tests in the testing solution (VS2008). Is that a too naive expectation :)

Answer (score 1):

This may sound stupid, but it's tripped me up more than once, are your test classes 1. Public and 2. Decorated with the [TestFixture()] attribute?

Also, your tests have the [Test] attribute, correct?

Comment: are your test classes 
1. Public YES
2. Decorated with the [TestFixture()] attribute? YES

Also, your tests have the [Test] attribute, correct? YES

Thanks for your interest but your answer is to cryptic for me :(
What should I do to make the tests work as they do with built in Microsoft MVC test templates?

Comment: "Resharper? NO. I was expecting it to work by menu/Test/Run all tests in the testing solution (VS2008). Is that a too naive expectation :) "

You can't run NUnit tests with Test/Run menu (I don't think.) Pretty sure that only does Microsoft Team Tests.  If you're writing NUnit tests, you'll need to use the NUnit Gui, console app, or something like Resharper, TestMatrix or TestDriven.Net

Comment: Ok, I have downloaded the evaluation ReSharper.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use Visual Studio Test Runner, you need to install the NUnit Test Adapter:

http://nunit.org/index.php?p=vsTestAdapter&r=2.6